# insertion in a table using select statement

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

Hi I am inserting values into a table using select statement. But insertion is not happening. There are 5 rows in result set of select statement. But when i fire insert statement with select data is not getting inserted into table.

I checked the sequence of attributes and everything seems to be right. I also tried to insert a single row in the table using "values" keyword and it is inserting data with help of that.
Why my insert is not working with the "select" command?

Please help its urgent.

Below is the query

```
insert into schema1.tabletemp
    select distinct 
    a.name as name,
    a.stu_number as rollno,
    c.userid as login_id,
    b.Address as stuAddress,
    b.totalgrades as FinalGrdaes
    ' ' as Misc
from
    Schema1.stu_info a, schema1.address_info b, schema1.logindetails c
where
    a.stu_no = b.record_no and
    a.status in ('Active') and 
   c.last_name=a.stu_lname and 
    c.first_name=a.stu_fname and  
    a.stu_no not in (select distinct student_number from schema1.student_final_records);
```

This query is trying to insert student data into tabletemp. The criteria is student records present in student_final_record table should not be inserted again. So any student number which is new in system i.e. which is not present in student_final_record will be inserted in tabletemp.

not in cLAUSE IN NOT WORKING. ANY SUGGESTIONS????

Comment: Please shjare your DDL, sample data, and insert query

Comment: Show us your sql, and maybe we can help.

Comment: Did you execute a COMMIT statement after the INSERT...SELECT?

Comment: insert into schema1.tabletemp
    select distinct 
    a.name as name,
    a.stu_number as rollno,
    c.userid as login_id,
    b.Address as stuAddress,
    b.totalgrades as FinalGrdaes
    ' ' as Misc
from
    Schema1.stu_info a, schema1.address_info b, schema1.logindetails c
where
    a.stu_no = b.record_no and
    a.status in ('Active') and 
   c.last_name=a.stu_lname and 
    c.first_name=a.stu_fname and  
    a.stu_no not in (select distinct student_number from schema1.student_final_records);

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma missing here:

```
   b.totalgrades as FinalGrdaes
    ' ' as Misc
```

The fixed version:

```
   b.totalgrades as FinalGrdaes,
    ' ' as Misc
```

Comment: Thanks I corrected it. I am using commit with insert statement but now it is inserting same rows all the time. I checked the use of "NOT IN " clause in query it is not working. Every time i am firing this query it is returning same rows.                                                                                                                                                                                                              select a.stu_no from schema1.tabletemp a
where a.stu_no not in (select student_number from schema2.student_final_record);

Comment: Thanks I corrected it. I am using commit with insert statement but now it is inserting same rows all the time. I checked the use of "NOT IN " clause in query it is not working. Every time i am firing this query it is returning same rows.                                                                                                                                    select a.stu_no from schema1.tabletemp a
where a.stu_no not in (select student_number from schema2.student_final_record);                                      I am not sure if this query is right. Please have a look and let me know

Comment: Your NOT IN clause addresses a table that is not included in the query, so nothing you do changes the values that this query will return.

Comment: Hi David Should i include the table used in subquery in main query as well